# UPower: PercentageLow, PercentageCritical - any meaning?

Tags: linux, power-management

My Linux uses `UPower` / `upowerd`. `PercentageAction` works, but I have not noticed anything happening on `PercentageLow` and `PercentageCritical`, as of now AFAIK they are only burden to make sure:

> If any value is invalid, or not in descending order, the defaults will
> be used.

I have not looked at the source code, only `man` pages and web search. Any usage for setting `PercentageLow` and `PercentageCritical`?